# Can I reassign eth1 and eth2 without rebooting the server

Tags: linux-networking

Say I have eth0 - my management interface,
then eth1 with mac1 and eth2 with mac 2- additional nics running.
How can I reassign eth1 with mac2 and eth2 with mac1 and bring them up without the reboot?

Comment: Why do you need to swap the mac adddress?

Comment: Put'em down, change addresses, then put'em up again.

Comment: What Linux distribution?

Comment: I tried to put them down, change the HWADDR entries in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 and ifcfg-eth2, change the entries in /etc/iftab, then do ifrename and service network restart or ifdown/ifup eth1 and eth2 - doesn't work without reboot. Any ideas?

Comment: put them down, change eth2 mac address first to other address, e.g: ifconfig eth2 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44, then ifconfig eth2 w.x.y.z netmask ww.xx.yy.zz up. do it for eth1 (using eth2 mac addr), and then change eth2 mac addr using old eth1 mac addr.

Comment: ifdown doesn't really makes the interface down. It looks and says but it doesn't totally. You will have to change a logic in those scripts(ifdown). Actually ifdown should restart the system, you will have to change that logic, so that system does not restart it.

Comment: sorry not in ifdown, in /etc/init.d/network script.

Answer (score 0):

Edit file `/etc/init.d/network`

You can comment/remove line `./ifdown $i boot` from below

```
action $"Shutting down interface $i: " ./ifdown $i boot
```

like this :

```
action $"Shutting down interface $i: " 

       # ./ifdown $i boot
```

to stop system from reboot on `/etc/init.d/network restart`.

You will have to check whether mac addresses gets changed by doing this. Or you will have to reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ip` command to change the name of an interface.

1. assign eth0 the new name swapit
2. assign eth1 the new name eth0
3. assign swapit the new name eth1